# How to aggregate the elements in a nested list

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
original_list = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O'],

                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],

                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

I want to aggregate each three list to be one list based on the majority of elements. That is, if two positions have the same element, the new list will take the same element in the same position.
The desired output should be like:

```
desired_output = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

I have tried with this complex function:

```
def collect_labels(lab_user):

  def aggregate_labels(a,b,c):
     aggregated_list = []
     # iterate over 3 lists
     for x,y,z in zip(a, b, c):
        if x != 'O':
          aggregated_list.append(x)
        elif y != 'O':
          aggregated_list.append(y)
        #elif z != 'O':
          #aggregated_list.append(z)  # you can improve the code
        else:
          aggregated_list.append(z)
     return aggregated_list

  result = [aggregate_labels(lab_user[i], lab_user[i+1], lab_user[i+2]) for i in range(0,len(lab_user)-2, 3)] 
  return result
```

But it return the wrong result:

```
wrong_result= [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
               ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
               ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O']]
```

I will be very grateful if you could help me to correct my code!

Comment: `[[statistics.mode(i) for i in zip(*j)] for j in (original_list[i*3:i*3+3] for i in range(len(original_list)//3))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broader solution using loop:

```
def merge_result(data):
    ar = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)-2, 3):
        temp = []        
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            if data[i][j] == data[i+1][j]:
                temp.append(data[i][j])
            elif data[i+2][j] == data[i+1][j]:
                temp.append(data[i+1][j])
            elif data[i][j] == data[i+2][j]:
                temp.append(data[i][j])
            else:
                temp.append('O')
        ar.append(temp)
    return ar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    original_list = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O'],

                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],

                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
    print(merge_result(original_list))
```

Output:

```
[['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Answer (score 3):

The hardest part of the problem is just grouping your lists into the three chunks:

```
>>> [original_list[i*3:i*3+3] for i in range(len(original_list)//3)]
[[['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O']], 
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']], 
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]]
```

Once you have that, though, you can use `zip` to group the items you want to compare:

```
>>> chunks = [original_list[i*3:i*3+3] for i in range(len(original_list)//3)]
>>> [list(zip(*j)) for j in chunks]
[[('B_S', 'B_S', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'B_S'), ('O', 'O', 'O')],
[('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('B_S', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'B_S', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'B_S'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O')], 
[('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('B_S', 'B_S', 'B_S'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('B_S', 'B_S', 'B_S'), ('B_S', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O')]]
```

And then you just want to pick the item in each of those zipped tuples that appears the most frequently -- aka `statistics.mode`:

```
>>> import statistics
>>> [[statistics.mode(i) for i in zip(*j)] for j in chunks]
[['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

or all together:

```
from statistics import mode

original_list = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O'],

                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],

                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
CHUNK_LEN = 3

desired_output = [
    [mode(i) for i in zip(*j)] 
    for j in (
        original_list[i*CHUNK_LEN:(i+1)*CHUNK_LEN] 
        for i in range(len(original_list)//CHUNK_LEN)
    )
]
```

Obviously if you can make `original_list` just be correctly grouped up front it's a lot easier:

```
from statistics import mode

original_list = [[['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O']],

                 [['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']],

                 [['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O']]]

desired_output = [
    [mode(i) for i in zip(*j)] 
    for j in original_list
]
```